# How to make sure an iPhone 7 has not been tampered with before purchase

Tags: iphone

I'm a bit skeptical about by iPhone 7 that I bought a few days ago. Its screen at the top is kind of feeling a bit weird, and I've heard a story of sellers here in my country removing the tamper sensors in iPhones before selling them. How do I know that it hasn't been opened, since if it has, it removes the water resistance of the iPhone?

Comment: By 'legit' do you mean 'not stolen'?

Comment: "Legit" can have one of several different meaning here.  Is it a fake iPhone 7 like a fake Rolex or fake Gucci bag?  Is the ESN good meaning it's not reported lost or stolen to the carrier.  Has the device been locked by the user/Apple as lost or stolen?  Consider rewriting your question with the specifics you are looking for.

Comment: No it's not stolen or anything. I was asking if it was possible to know if it had been modified in any way. I ran AnTuTu on it, and it said my device is unknown. It could be AnTuTu's problem, it has warranty on the serial number and it shows up in iCloud as iPhone 7

Comment: @fbara no that is not what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Buy your device from a reputable company.

(Apple, BestBuy, AT&T, etc)

That's the only surefire way you are going to know that the phone (or device) you just shelled the equivalent of a half a rent check for a non-ocean view 600 sq. ft. studio in Miami Beach is of the highest quality, reliability and most importantly ***authenticity***.

As always, the old adage always holds true:  [If it's too good to be true, it probably is](http://fortune.com/2015/07/27/police-china-fake-iphones/).

Now, the [iPhone 7 has been out less than a month since being released](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_7) and you are buying one through the secondary market, you should be wary.  There may be nothing wrong with it, but given that carriers and major retailers give you 15 days to return for a full refund...you have to wonder why they are selling it already.

Comment: It's been released since September 16th. It's just hard to get. I've asked around, and the seller is reputable, and someone I know has gotten a MacBook Pro from there, and apple did fix it, whereas a modified device apple refused to fix. I've got 1 year of extended warranty with them, and if apple refuses to fix it for an issue, I can go to them and tell them. I got it from Sharaf DG here in the UAE.

Comment: I think I'll use this iPhone since the store is a very big electronics store here, and I do not think it would make any sense. Someone told me a story of someone buying a iPhone from a different place here, and that happening to them. I only suspected it because of some little noise that came from the screen when I tapped it, and when I opened the phone it's screen protector had no adhesive from the back, which I suspect is a new thing with apple maybe.

Comment: Ahhh... Hard to get *in the UAE.*  I can't speak for the availability in your area, but your strategy seems sound.

Comment: Yeah it's really hard since there's only 2 apple stores in the entire country.

Comment: I might be crazy, but I found an unboxing video of the iPhone 7 matte black. It didn't have any stickiness on the back either, and mine came in its original packaging. Maybe I can actually enjoy my phone now :)

Comment: Those unboxing videos do come in handy from time to time.